# How to render dynamically crated RMarkdown in the console

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have functions that create html and markdown.  For html I can make the html rendered correctly inside a Quarto or RMarkdown chunk by passing the created character strings through `htmltools::HTML()`, and to make them rendered from the console I just use `htmltools::browsable(htmltools(HTML(strings)))`.  When I produce markdown, e.g. a $\LaTeX$ math expression such as `$\alpha$` I can render in a chunk by passing the string through `knitr::asis_output`.  For both approaches I need not bother with `results='asis'` in the chunk header.  When outside a chunk the html is rendered in the RStudio View panel or by popping up your default browser if not in RStudio.

Is there a corresponding way to render constructed markdown strings in a view window from the console?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You want to render it and view it at the same time or just render it into html? try the `rmarkdown::render` function

Comment: I want to render the small character vector containing markdown (especially math) and to have the result appear in a  browser popup (if not under RStudio) or in the RStudio Viewer panel.

Comment: Use of `rmarkdown::render` as suggested by @onyambu worked great.  I wrote a little function wrote the input strings to a temporary file, run that function, `readLines()` to get back into character vectors, and `htmltools::browsable(htmltools::HTML))` the result of that.  I had to prepend a little `RMarkdown` YAML header to the strings before passing to `render`.

Comment: rendHTML <- function(x, html=TRUE) {
  x <- paste(x, collapse='\n')

  if(length(getOption('knitr.in.progress'))) {
    if(html) x <- paste0('```{=html}\n', x, '\n```')
    return(knitr::asis_output(x))
  }
  if(! html) {  # Convert from RMarkdown to html
    tf <- tempfile(fileext='.Rmd')
    o  <- tempfile(fileext='.html')
    cat('---\ntitle: ""\npagetitle: x\noutput: html_document\n---\n',
        x, '\n', sep='', file=tf)
    rmarkdown::render(tf, output_file=o, quiet=TRUE)
    x <- readLines(o)
    }
  print(htmltools::browsable(htmltools::HTML(x)))
}